# how to configure replication(read-replica) for MS-SQL in Cloud SQL?

Tags: sql-server, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I am exploring Cloud SQL and the various flavours (MySQL, PostgreSQL, MS-SQL). I am able to create read replicas for MySQL and PostgreSQL, but I don't find that option for MS-SQL. Is it possible to create read replica of MS-SQL cloud database created in Cloud-SQL without using any third party support?

**Note**: Also I find the documentation is missing the ms-sql read replica pages.

FYI the screenshot I got from the Cloud-SQL options:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go to [this page](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/feature_support) and check the available feature in each database engine. Replication is not yet available for SQL Server.

But I remember having viewed something in the roadmap. Maybe later this year! Stay tuned.